# Correct way to apply clipped prop to <v-navigation-bar/> in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

Unsure of correct way to apply clipped prop to `<v-navigation-draw/>` in vuetify application to force the navigation drawer to sit below the app-bar. What I've tried.

Created a fresh project:

```
$ vue create mylayout
$ cd mylayout
$ vue add vuetify
```

Cut & paste the `Baseline` pre-made layout (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/pre-made-layouts/) into `src/App.vue`

Edit the `<v-navigation-drawer/>`

```
<v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      app
      clipped         <--- added this prop
>
```

Edit the `<v-app-bar/>`

```
<v-app-bar
  app
  color="indigo"
  dark
  clipped-left        <--- added this prop
>
```

View in FireFox 75.0, and click the app-bar Hamburger icon, and the navigation drawer 'pops over' the app-bar.  I've poured over the docs and samples for hours with no-joy. I know I'm missing something, but it's escaping me.

Comment: Instead of cutting and pasting the layout, just use [this codepen](https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/zgxeLQ). There are no issues with your instructions in FF 75.0. Works fine. Double check your work.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I tested in codepen & it worked as expected. I feel like codepen is suppressing details required for a complete picture. For example, where is the index.html that glues it all together?  The steps I listed are the canonical steps recommended by vuetify, but they do not work & I'm at a loss on how to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the navigation clipped issue and how it interacts with other properties with just a few added lines.

The basic issue is that the clipped prop does not work without also applying the 'permanent' prop to v-navigation-drawer.

So... simply adding the 'permanent' prop fixes the issue. However:

What if you want it to hide reactively as if you didnt need to apply the permanent prop?
Use v-if on v-navigation-drawer with the same field as you use on the v-model prop, then wrap the entire thing in a v-expand-x-transition.

Example:

```
<v-expand-x-transition appear>
    <v-navigation-drawer>
        v-if="drawer"
        v-model="drawer"
        app
        clipped
        permanent
    >
</v-expand-x-transition>
```

edit:
To make the transition smooth on the first time it appears, give the v-expand-x-transition the  'appear' prop

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the `VNavigationDrawer` component's `isMobile` computed property.  I had my personal view in FireFox zoomed in. Vuetify considered my view to equate to the component being rendered on a mobile device and ignored the clipped prop.

The solution is to either extend the `VNavigationBar` component and drop the check for `isMobile`, or is zoom out (I choose to zoom out).

In case anyone else stumbles across this, I've included the relevant isMobile() calculation below and included the comment.

```
isMobile (): boolean {
  return (
    !this.stateless &&
    !this.permanent &&
    // The next line is the check for a mobile-width view
    this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width < parseInt(this.mobileBreakPoint, 10)
  )
},
```